# \pagestyle{empty} doesn't seem to work for page with \maketitle

Tags: header-footer, titles

In the LaTeX document pasted below, I still see page numbers upon compiling, even though I've included a `\pagestyle{empty}` command below the `\maketitle` command. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

```
\title{Thesis Abstracts}
\author{
        Kurt Han Peek
}
\date{\today}

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\pagestyle{empty}

\section*{An Analysis of the Effects of Digital Phase Errors on the Performance of a FMCW-Doppler Radar}
In modern frequency-modulated continuous-wave (FMCW) radars, the transmitter is increasingly being implemented using direct digital chirp synthesis (DDCS), which provides improvements in sweep linearity, stability, precision, agility, and versatility over analog techniques. Its main limitations are errors due to sampling of the modulating signal, phase truncation, and digital-to-analog converter (DAC) quantization, which produce spurious signals due to their deterministic nature. This thesis presents an analysis and simulation of the effect of two sources of digital phase errors -- namely, sampling of the modulating signal and phase truncation -- on the performance of a FMCW-Doppler transceiver employing a DDCS in its transmitter. An upper bound for the amplitude of spurious targets resulting from these digital phase errors is established. Further, it is shown that provided the phase errors are periodic with the sweep period, the spurious targets are not offset from the target in Doppler. An algorithm for selecting the digital chirp parameters of a DDCS so as to ensure periodic and phase-continuous sweep transitions, which guarantee periodic phase errors and reduce `spectral splatter', is devised. Finally, we investigate parallels of FMCW radar in the optical domain, and consider the fundamental question whether range resolution is fundamentally limited by the bandwidth of a transmitted signal, or its carrier frequency.

\section*{Estimation and Compensation of Frequency Sweep Nonlinearity in FMCW radar}
One of the main issues limiting the range resolution of linear frequency-modulated continuous-wave (FMCW) radars is nonlinearity of frequency sweep, which results in degradation of contrast and range resolution, especially at long ranges. Two novel, slightly different, methods to correct for frequency sweep nonlinearity by digital post-processing of the deramped signal were introduced independently by Burgos-Garcia et al. (Burgos-Garcia, Castillo et al. 2003) and Meta et al. (Meta, Hoogeboom et al. 2006). In these publications, however, no formal proof of the techniques was given, and no limitations were described. In this thesis, we prove that the algorithm of Meta is exact for temporally infinite chirps, and remains valid for finite chirps with time-bandwidth products which are large compared to unity, provided the maximum frequency component of the phase error function is small compared to the square root of the nominal chirp rate. It is also shown that the algorithm of Meta reduces to that of Burgos-Garcia in this limit. A digital implementation of both methods described. Finally, we propose a novel method to measure the systematic phase errors which are required as input to the compensation algorithm.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

`\maketitle` (without the `titlepage` class option) internally uses `\thispagestyle{plain}` which locally overrides `\pagestyle{empty}`. Add `\thispagestyle{empty}` immediately after `\maketitle`.