# \pagestyle{empty} not working for first page

Tags: header-footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [\pagestyle{empty} doesn’t seem to work for page with \maketitle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44280/pagestyleempty-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-page-with-maketitle)

I have a document. For the remaining pages, there are no page numbers, but only for the first one I want the number to be removed
MWE is:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,12pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,bottom=0.95in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\title{ABCD}
\author{efg

%\vspace{3mm}
Electrical Engineering\\
University\\
address\\
email: $\{$email $\}$}
\markboth{}{}

\maketitle
\pagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `\thispagestyle{empty}` instead of `\pagestyle{empty}`:

```
\documentclass[onecolumn,12pt]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage[left=1in,right=1in,bottom=0.95in,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\title{ABCD}
\author{efg

%\vspace{3mm}
Electrical Engineering\\
University\\
address\\
email: $\{$email $\}$}
\markboth{}{}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: this works! I had to again add \pagestyle{empty} before \begin{document} to suppress it in other pages