# How to use \maketitle without make it a title page so the header and footer wouldn't change?

Tags: header-footer, titles

If I use `\title`, then it changes the page style. How do I display information like title, author and date with out make it a title page?

Or how to show header and footer on title page?

The code is bad since I learn this yesterday.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%set page header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Com S 311: Homework 1}
\chead{Daolin Cheng}
\rhead{\today}
%\cfoot{Page \thepage}


\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}


\titlelabel{\thetitle}% reduce the space after section title
%\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]
%{\normalfont\large\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{} %text can follow subsection title




\begin{document}
%\pagestyle{fancy}
%\fancypagestyle{plain}


\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}% default is 0pt





\section*{Problem 1}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}

\subsection{) $12|\mathbb{N}\subseteq3|\mathbb{N}$} 

Proof:



\subsection{) $35|\mathbb{N}=5|\mathbb{N}\cap7|\mathbb{N}$} Proof:



%\newpage
\section*{Problem 2}
For arbitrary sets A, B, prove:
\setcounter{subsection}{0}%reset numbering
\subsection{) $A\cup B=B\Longleftrightarrow A\subseteq B$}
\subsection{) $A\cap B=B\Longleftrightarrow B\subseteq A$}
\subsection{) $A-(A-B)\subseteq B$}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip} %add one blank line
And prove there exists sets A,B such that:
\subsection{) $B\nsubseteq A-(A-B)$}
\section*{Problem 3}
Give an example of a function $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ that is both one-to-            one and onto.
\section*{Problem 4}
Let $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ be a function defined as $f(x)=3x+7$. Prove:
\setcounter{subsection}{0}%reset numbering
\subsection{) $f$ is one-to-one}
\subsection{) $f$ is NOT onto}

\section*{Problem 5}
Let $\sim$ be a relation over the real numbers such that for $a,b\in\mathbb{R}, a\sim b$     if and only if $a-b\in\mathbb{Z}$. Prove that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.


\section*{Problem 6}
Use the well-ordering principle to prove that proofs by induction are valid. More     precisely, prove that if: $P:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \{T,F\}$ is a predicate with the     following properties,
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}
\setcounter{subsection}{0} %reset numbering
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\hspace{2em}}{\thesubsection}{1pt}{.\quad} %add     indent, space after number and text followed
\subsection{$P(0)=T$}
\subsection{$P(n)=T\Rightarrow P(n+1)=T$}
then $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}, P(n)=T$.


\section*{Problem 7}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection}}    
\setcounter{subsection}{0} %reset numbering
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\hspace{2em}}{\thesubsection}{1pt}{)\quad}
\subsection{$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,}
$$1+3+5+\cdots+2n-1=n^2$$
\subsection{$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,}
$$3^n>2^n$$
\subsection{$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,}
$$\sum_{i=1}^ni=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
\subsection{$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}^+$,}
\begin{center}
$n^3+2n$ is divisible by 3
\end{center}




\section*{Bonus Problem}
\paragraph{\indent}%add indent to paragraph
A friend of yours challenges you to a game skittles. The game requires two piles each     containing exactly N skittles. On a player's turn, the player removes some (non-zero) number of skittles from exactly one of the piles. The player that takes the last skittle, wins!
\paragraph{\indent}
Your friend decides to go first. Describe a strategy that ensures that you will always win. Prove its correctness using induction.




\end{document}
```

Comment: What code do you currently have?

Comment: Your example doesn't show the problem you're currently experiencing with so-called `\title`... Please update.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: Let me suggest improvements to your code. Use `\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection})}` and omit the `)`-s in the subsection titles. Use `\indent`, then a newline, to start an indented paragraph. `\paragraph` is for printing the paragraph title.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44280/pagestyleempty-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-page-with-maketitle/44281#44281

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can just issue `\thispagestyle` immediately after `\maketitle`:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{titlesec}

%set page header and footer
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{Com S 311: Homework 1}
\chead{First Last}
\rhead{\today}

\usepackage[left=4cm,right=4cm,top=4cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}

\titlelabel{\thetitle\enspace}

\begin{document}
\title{Homework 1}
\author{First Last}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{fancy}

\section*{Problem 1}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\alph{subsection})}

\subsection{$12|\mathbb{N}\subseteq3|\mathbb{N}$} 

Proof:

\subsection{$35|\mathbb{N}=5|\mathbb{N}\cap7|\mathbb{N}$} Proof:

\newpage
\section*{Problem 2}
For arbitrary sets A, B, prove:
\setcounter{subsection}{0}%reset numbering
\subsection{$A\cup B=B\Longleftrightarrow A\subseteq B$}
\subsection{$A\cap B=B\Longleftrightarrow B\subseteq A$}
\subsection{$A-(A-B)\subseteq B$}
\vspace*{1\baselineskip} %add one blank line
And prove there exists sets A,B such that:
\subsection{$B\nsubseteq A-(A-B)$}

\end{document}
```