# How do I remove header and footer from contents page and list of figures

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

This is the code I've used for the header and footer. How do I remove header and footer from contents page and list of figures?

```
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\rhead{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{2014-2015}}}
\lhead{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{ECG SIMULATION AND ACQUISITION}}}
\rfoot{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{\thepage}}}
\lfoot{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{Dept. of ECE, RNSIT, BANGALORE}}}
```

Comment: information in this question may be useful: [\pagestyle{empty} doesn't seem to work for page with \maketitle](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/44280/579)

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}%
}
```

in the preamble. If there are more than one page in the table of contents or list of figures you have to use `\pagestyle{empty}` additionally.

Example:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\rhead{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{2014-2015}}}
\lhead{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{ECG SIMULATION AND ACQUISITION}}}
\rfoot{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{\thepage}}}
\lfoot{\fontsize{10}{12}\selectfont \textit{\textbf{Dept. of ECE, RNSIT, BANGALORE}}}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}%
  \addtocontents{lof}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\begin{document}
%
\pagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
%
\clearpage
\pagestyle{fancy}
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument\Blinddocument
\begin{figure}
  \fbox{Figure}
  \caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you use a KOMA-Script class

```
\AfterTOCHead{\thispagestyle{empty}}
```

removes the header and footer from the first page of table of contents and all lists that are controlled by KOMA-Script.