# Adjust page numbering and linenumbers

Tags: page-numbering, line-numbering

everyone. I need to set the line numbering in the following template so that it also counts the title. Line 5 should be line 6 and so on. Moreover, I need to set the page numbering in all pages as "1/2", "2/2" and so on (including the first page). How can I do that?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\setlength{\droptitle}{4cm}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{notitle}
\author{}
\date{}
\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\linespread{1.25}
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalsize}
\setlength{\headheight}{20mm}
\begin{document}
\maketitle\vspace{-4cm}
\linenumbers
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document).

Comment: I used that answer to make my code but I can't make all the pages with the same numbering style (including the first page).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough this is not with `\maketitle` it's an alternative. But if you still want to use `\maketitle` [this questions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44280/pagestyleempty-doesnt-seem-to-work-for-page-with-maketitle) has the same question. As `\maketitle` sets the page style to plain.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[modulo]{lineno}
\usepackage[left=3cm,right=3cm,top=2cm,bottom=4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead[C]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\linespread{1.25}
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalsize}
\setlength{\headheight}{20mm}

\begin{document}
{\centering \section*{notitle}}

\linenumbers
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Putting the \linenumbers before {\centering \section*{notitle}} also gives the right numbering :)